# UIImage: strange issue with size

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage

Im trying to download "profile_image_url" images (.jpg) from twitter and display them in my app.  Im trying to resize any images that are not what I'm expecting them to be.  In the process of debugging an issue, I ran into this strange behavior.

Code:

```
NSLog(@"%d  %d  %d  %d",48,image.size.width,image.size.height,48);
```

Prints:

```
2010-02-09 13:26:43.925 MyApp[00000:0000] 48  0  1078460416  0
```

It appears that the height and width is not printing properly and also causes the second "48" not to print.  What is going on here?

BTW, the UIImage displays fine I just cannot resize the image properly if i cannot get the width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%d is for integers. Use %f for printing floats (which is what the CGSize members are).

Answer (score 0):

`image.size` is a `CGSize` which stores `width` and `height` as floats, not ints.  So use `%f` in your format string instead.